# How to Schedule any script on Salt-Master

Tags: salt-stack

We are new in the salt stack. Our use case is to Schedule a run python/go script on salt-master. Is there any way or configuration to do the same?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can schedule anything: [Job Management](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/topics/jobs/index.html#scheduling-jobs)

To run a script from the master process (not a minion):

```yaml
schedule:
  job1:
    function: salt.cmd
    args:
      - cmd.run
      - /path/to/script
    when: whenever
```

That uses the [`salt.cmd`](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/runners/all/salt.runners.salt.html#salt.runners.salt.cmd) runner to run the [`cmd.run`](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.cmdmod.html#salt.modules.cmdmod.run) function on the master, running the given script.

If you have a minion on the master server, you can use that instead and save a level of indirection.